# Why is this query ignoring the WHERE clause?

Tags: where-clause

This is driving me mad now.

My query is ignoring the WHERE clause and just outputting all results.

I know it is still reading the script because when i change the script to something ridiculous such as WHERE user=xxx is throws back an error.

Help?

```
$data = mysql_query(
        "SELECT 

        tbl_messages.id as msgID, 
        tbl_messages.from_user as msgFROM,
        tbl_messages.to_user as msgTO, 
        tbl_messages.the_message as msgMESSAGE, 
        tbl_messages.status as msgSTATUS, 
        tbl_messages.date as msgDATE, 
        tbl_messages.subject as msgSUBJECT,

        tbl_users.id as usrID, 
        tbl_users.name as usrNAME,

        tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
        tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
        tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT  

        FROM tbl_messages 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_users 
        ON tbl_messages.from_user = tbl_users.id 

        LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 

        WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = 65 AND tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
        ORDER BY status DESC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a guess, but you probably need some parens around parts of the `WHERE` clause; it's probably evaluating to `true` for all rows, as written.

```
WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = 65
    AND (tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1')
```

Comment: Wait, no - hold the phone. You're right! I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need it too look like this:

```
WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = 65 
AND tbl_photos.default_photo ='NULL' OR tbl_photos.default_photo = 1
ORDER BY status DESC
```

or like this:

```
WHERE tbl_messages.to_user = 65 
AND tbl_photos.default_photo ='NULL' OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
ORDER BY status DESC
```